# Unusual shape in partial residual plot

Tags: regression, generalized-linear-model, residuals

I have a health insurance data set (roughly 200,000 records on the policy level) where I'm modeling the estimated paid loss cost for disease X using a GLM. One of the predictors is `paid amount / patient count`, `paid amount` being the invoice amount hospitals charge to treat patients with disease X and `patient count`, which is the number of patients in the hospital being treated for disease X.

I'm looking to transform `paid amount / patient count`, but when producing the partial residual plot I get output that looks strange. I'm wondering what sort of reasons might cause this and what can be done to fix it.

[image]

The distribution of `paid amount / patient count` is quite skewed. For instance, the five-number summary of this predictor is

```
Min.    1st Qu.  Median    Mean    3rd Qu.    Max. 
0.0     1.1      3.0       4.1     5.80       70.0
```

which I think is probably due to low credibility (i.e. low patient count) for some rows. The response variable, the paid loss cost, is also zero-inflated.

Comment: It is clearly wrong functional form that you ve chose. Also, nonnormality is an alarm for this.

Comment: This looks like there's some important unaccounted-for factor, but it might perhaps be an artifact of a low patient count on the denominator (or both together; low patient counts might tend to correspond to expensive treatments, say). It would be worth trying to figure out why those patients are different from the others. I'd try colouring the points by patient count and also looking for differences in (say) calendar time (/ changes to costs) and similar factors between the arms

Comment: It turns out I just incorrectly produced the partial residual plot (as the function that produces the plot is user-defined). I appreciate the responses here though, as they were useful for diagnostic checking.